# Why are serialized objects of the same class different in two different projects

Tags: java, swing, servlets

So I had two projects. One of them was `servlet` and another one was `JFrame`. I tried to read serialized object in `servlet`, but i got `ClassNotFoundException`. And only when I put all classes and compiled them  in my `servlet` project it began to work. Is it the way it should work? Does the `serialization` depends on the project it was compiled?(if the classes of course are the same)

**UPD** Definitions of my class for example Figure was in both `servlet` and `JFrame` class.

Comment: We need a lot more info to be able to help you here.

Comment: Did the jars exist in both projects classpath?

Answer (score 2):

From [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/objects/storing/serial.html)

```
When an object is serialized, information that identifies its class is recorded in
the serialized stream. However, the class's definition ("class file") itself is
not recorded. It is the responsibility of the system that is deserializing the
object to determine how to locate and load the necessary class files.
```

Comment: Thx, but the problem is that i had class's definition in both projects. And these classes were exactly the same.

Comment: Your serializable object must be having an reference to some another object(serializable of course) which it could not find. make sure all such classes are present while deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

De-serialization will require the .class file to create the object from the serialized stream. As the serialized object does not contain the class definition, so there is no way to extract the object out of the stream without having the .class file.